# bad request 400 when trying to POST request a form

Tags: forms, mongoose

I got an error for a bad request and a warning required path schema from mongoose even though the state and route match the mongoose

[image]};

//state

```
const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
const [books, setBooks] = useState("");
const [writer, setWriter] = useState("");
```

//handle Submit

```
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const feetchData = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/books", {
  method: "POST",
  Headers: {
    "Content-type": "application / json",
  },
  Body: JSON.stringify(data),
});
```

//controler

```
 const postNewBooks = async (req, res) => {
 const { title, writer, books } = req.body;
 try {
 const data = await book.create({ title, writer, books });
 res.status(200).send(data);
 } catch (error) {
 res.status(400).json({ error: error.message });
 console.log(error.message);
 }
```

Comment: The correct Content-Type is `application/json` - you introduced arbitrary spaces in there, so the receiver will in all likelihood _not_ know how to parse this request.

Comment: i try this , but still getting validation warning from mongoose

Comment: What is the actual `data` you are sending?

Comment: I console log it in the backend and it actually send undefined undefined undefined but why

Comment: Probably because it did not contain what you thought it should on the client side already - so go check there.

Comment: yes it did not goes to the back end server while using fetch, I try to use axios instead and suddenly it all work and much more simplier

Answer (score 0):

this is the feth code that failed me it didn't go to the backend server I try cathing the data in req.body.data but got undefined

```
  const feetchData = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/books", {
  method: "POST",
  Header: {
    "Content-type": "application/json",
  },
  Body: JSON.stringify(data),
  });
  return feetchData.json();
```

i used axios instead and it works well

```
   axios
  .post("http://localhost:5000/books", data)
  .then((item) => {
    console.log(item);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```